# There are two hover message when my cursor over the python code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[image: Screen shot]

What I have tried:

1. Reboot the system. Done but nothing happens.
2. Uninstall the pylance and python extension. Done but nothing happens.
3. Install vscode insider and open the same jupyter notebook file. Done but the same issue still occurs.
4. Switch different conda virtual environments. Done but the same issue still occurs.

Comment: this is surely some plugin you have installed for vscode ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Add a GitHub link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11938

Upgrading the jupyter extension to the pre-release version (2022.11.1003131031) solved the problem.

---

It may be an exception brought by the version update, resulting in repeated code prompts.

Rolling back the **Python** extension version to `v2022.16.1` fixed the problem.

Open the python extension page and select `Install Another Version...`

[image]

select `2022.16.1` version

[image]

Restart vscode after installation is complete

[image]

Comment: Thank you,  the issue has been solved after re-installing the vscode-jupyter extension with the latest version.