# Remove duplicate suggestions in vscode Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pylance

While working in Jupyter Notebooks inside VS code (almost) every completion suggestion is duplicated, see example below. And it's very annoying to work with.

[image]

Versions used:

- python: 3.9.8
- vs code: 1.78.2
- vscode Jupyter extension: v2023.4.1011241018
- vscode pylance extension: v2023.5.50

I'm at a point where I'm not sure where to look. I've tried enabling/disabling the Pylance extension (the likely culprit), switching to pre-release version of both the Jupyter and Pylance extensions and searching through the extensions settings for a solution but haven't found anything.

I did come across https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11938 which lists a similar issue but those issues were apparently resolved in newer versions which I'm already on.

This only happens in Jupyter notebooks, regular python files all works as intended (see below)

[image]

Comment: duplicates is a lot better than no suggestions, it is all open source so if you find the cause make a PR

Comment: I have used the same version of `Pylance` and `Jupyter` as you, but have not encountered the same problem. You can try the method in [this answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12029#issuecomment-1423137871) and switch the version to pre-release.

Comment: meta note: related to the issue ticket you linked of the _historical_ issue with hover info (not suggestions) 11938: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74384520/11107541